# Is $(u\cdot\nabla)v\in H^1$, if $u,v\in H^2$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, fluid-dynamics

Let

- $d\in\left\{2,3\right\}$ with
- $\Lambda\subseteq\mathbb R^d$ be bounded and open with $\partial\Lambda\in C^1$

In [Lemma 6.1](https://books.google.de/books?id=W9shWJXh-SEC&pg=PA44&lpg=PA44&dq=%22since+the+first+derivatives+of%22+%22are+continuous+on%22&source=bl&ots=wgz76uXDbe&sig=Y8nT5AH6RbktZk-wXdRQTupAXCE&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiNpbfcg-_QAhXHFCwKHUEdAcUQ6AEIHTAA) of *Navier-Stokes Equations and Nonlinear Functional Analysis* by *Roger Temam*, the author is stating that if $u,v\in H^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$, then $$\frac\partial{\partial x_i}(u\cdot\nabla)v=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\cdot\nabla\right)v+(u\cdot\nabla)\frac{\partial v}{\partial x_i}\tag 1$$ would belong to $L^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$, because $u,v$ belong to $L^6(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$ and $u,v$ are continuous on $\overline\Lambda$ (which is clear by the Sobolev inequalities as they can be found, for example, in the [book of Evans](https://books.google.de/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&pg=PA286&lpg=PA286&dq=%22evans%22+%22General+Sobolev+inequalities%22+%22be+a+bounded+open%22&source=bl&ots=dkidsCTqpS&sig=Nn7_q90n09Sw8TQS8vTQhJ4IfDI&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9yvGWp-_QAhUBCSwKHQSHDm8Q6AEIIzAB#v=onepage&q=%22evans%22%20%22General%20Sobolev%20inequalities%22%20%22be%20a%20bounded%20open%22&f=false)).

Can the same statement be proved, if $\Lambda$ is just bounded and open and $u,v\in H_0^2(\Lambda,\mathbb R^d)$?

Comment: It also follows from Sobolev embedding.

Comment: @FanZheng Of course, you're right (the crucial point is that $d\le 3$). I didn't saw this at the first place, cause I got a domain in mind which is just bounded and open. I've modified the question accordingly.

Comment: Well, $H_0^2$ by definition is the completion of $C_c^\infty$ in $H^2$ norm, so in this case the limiting sequence converges uniformly, and it has nothing to do with the regularity of the boundary. (Or could $H_0^2$ mean something else (like div/curl free vector fields) in the context of the NS equation?)

Comment: @FanZheng $H_0^2$ is the completion of $C_c^\infty$ with respect to the $H^2$-norm, sure, but how do you intend to conclude that $(1)$ is in $L^2$ from that?

Comment: If a function is in $H^2_0$, it can be extended by zero outside the domain, and the extended function is in $H^2$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy Yes, but how should that help? What I need is $W_k^p(\Lambda)\subseteq C^0(\overline\Lambda)$, if $k>d/p$, in the case where $\Lambda$ is just bounded and open. For $p=2$, I've found this statement in your book (Lemma 7.27) in the case where $\Lambda$ has the $k$-extension property. However, you deal with the stronger statement that the embedding is compact there. So, maybe we can always find a continuous representative in the bounded and open case, but I couldn't find a reference.

Comment: If the functions are in $H^2_0$, you do not need the extension property because you can extend by zero.

Comment: @0xbadf00d For the first term, $\nabla u$ and $\nabla v$ are in $H_0^1$, which embeds in $L^6$. For the second term, it is $L^\infty$ multiplied by $L^2$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy I'm a computer scientist, so, please be patient and let me try to understand this. We have $Λ⊆\mathbb R^d$, $d\inℕ$ arbitrary, being bounded and open (and I stress the fact that $Λ$ doesn't need to be connected, i.e. a domain). Now, if $u∈ H_0^2(Λ)$, we can find $(u_n)_{n\inℕ}⊆ C_c^∞(Λ)$ such that $\left\|u_n-u\right\|_{H^2(Λ)}\xrightarrow{n\to∞}0$ by definition of $H^2(Λ)$. Since $Λ$ is bounded, we can find a ball $B_r(0)$ around $0$ with radius $r>0$ such that $Λ⊆ B_r(0)$. Now, we can simply extend the $u_n$ to $B_r(0)$ by zero. Denote these extensions by $\overline u_n$.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy It's clear that $\overline u_n∈ C_c^∞(B_r(0))$ for all $n\inℕ$. Obviously, $(\overline u_n)_{n\inℕ}$ is convergent in $H^2(B_r(0))$. Call the limit $v$. Since $\partial B_r(0)\in C^1$, we can apply the argument from the question and find a continuous representative of $v$ which can be continuously extended to $\overline{B_r(0)}$. If we extend $u$ by zero to $B_r(0)$ and call the extension $\overline u$, it's easy to see that $\left\|\overline u-v\right\|_{H^2(B_r(0))}=0$, i.e. $\overline u=v$ a.e. and we're done. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: @0xbadf00d Beware that if $d\ge4$, then $H^2$ does not embed into $L^\infty$, let alone $C_0$, so there is some luck in that the NS equation is usually posted in 2 or 3 dimensions.

Comment: @FanZheng I'm not sure, if I understand what you mean. We've got $W^{k,\:p}\subseteq C^0$, if $k>d/p$. Thus, $H^2\subseteq C^0$, if $d<4$. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Exactly. (Placeholder text)